# HttpPost giving error in API 23 android

Tags: android, http, http-post, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a method in my android app which uses HttpPost class.
It was working fine with targeted sdk 4.4.2 but i've made some changes and made the targeted sdk to 23(6.0).
Now HttpPost class is giving error.
I've also read about HttpUrlConnection but don't know how to use it.
Here is my code

```
private String getJSON(String URL, JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        String responseString = null;
        try {

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
            httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            httppost.setEntity(se);

            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            System.out.println("status code is" + statusCode);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("response string" + responseString);
            Log.i("RESPONSE XML ------> ", "-----> " + responseString);
            return responseString;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseString;
    }
```

Please help what can i do or if possible provide this function with classes that will work on 23.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i'm just getting cannot be resolved into type error. And there is no option to import anything but as soon as i change the targeted sdk to 4.4.2 it works fine.

Comment: Can you post stack trace? So it can be more clear.

Comment: Can you add your code for `build.gradle`?

Comment: I am using eclipse IDE and i cannot paste the stack trace here because it is not running and showing the error- "Cannot be resolved into type" on class HttpPost and HttpParams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code inside function with  below given code, using **HttpUrlConnection**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class TestJava {

private String getJSON(String URL, JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        //Create connection
        url = new URL(URL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/json");
        connection.setUseCaches (false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                connection.getOutputStream ());
        wr.write(obj.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        wr.flush ();
        wr.close ();

        //Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {

        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: this code is not working i've tried and this is still getting me into the error block

Comment: @raviraghav, add these import statement if you haven't added it yet. `import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;`

Comment: @raviraghav, `import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import net.arnx.jsonic.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;`

Comment: Above import are all the imports you need to run your method `private String getJSON(String URL, JSONObject obj) throws JSONException`. I have tried the same code in eclipse and it is working properly without any compile time error.

Comment: same code is getting me in the error block
Can you please post your working code here.

Comment: @raviraghav, I have edited my answer. I have put your function inside my `TestJava` class. I have also included all the necessary import required.